# How do I differentiate between variable types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I want to write a function that determines if the two variables passed in are of the same data type, such as string, integer, boolean etc. However, I have no idea as to how to compare the two variables in term of their DATA TYPES instead of the VALUES stored inside the variables.

Thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to find out the data type of a variable. So to test two variables for same type (not necessarily same value), you can use

```
if(typeof a == typeof b) { /* same type */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typeof` as suggested, but it's not perfect; an array and a Date instance will both be considered to be of type "object".

Another imperfect way to compare by type is this:

```
function sameTypes() {
  var tp = null, ts = Object.prototype.toString;
  if (arguments.length === 0) return true; // or false if you prefer
  tp = ts.call(arguments[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i)
    if (tp !== ts.call(arguments[i])) return false;
  return true;
}
```

You can pass that function two or more (well one or more I guess) values and it'll return `true` if the result of calling the "toString" function on the Object prototype is the same for all of them. This one's not perfect because it promotes primitives to objects, so a string constant will seem to have the same type as a String instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

Use typeof()

```
var test = true,
    test2 = "string";

if (typeof(test) === typeof(test2)) {}
```